# Provide custom injector to dynamically created external + AOT-compiled component

Tags: angular

We are working on a widget-style system where, using Angular 8 (no Ivy), we want to provide AOT compiled components which are loaded through SystemJS and then rendered. For this we are essentially following [alexzuza's approach](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-plugin-architecture/tree/cli8). Building, bundling, importing and rendering the components works fine.

However, I now want to provide a custom injector to the component that is being created. In my mind this should be as easy as

```
const injector = Injector.create({
    parent: this.injector,
    providers: [
        { provide: MY_TOKEN, useValue: 42 },
    ],
});

const compRef = this.container.createComponent(compFactory, 0, injector);

// Both of these work
console.log(injector.get(MY_TOKEN)); // 42
console.log(compRef.injector.get(MY_TOKEN)); // 42
```

However, if we change the plugin to inject this token:

```
constructor(@Inject(MY_TOKEN) private value: number) {}
```

… we just get an error because the token cannot be found:

> ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(…)[o -> InjectionToken MY_TOKEN]

---

Is there something specific about AOT compiled components that prevents this from working? Inspecting the bundle everything looks the way I would expect and there's no issue of mangled names in the injection token or anything like that.

How can I properly provide a custom injector to a component which comes from an external resource?

Comment: Can you try using a `string` as a token? `{ provide: 'MY_TOKEN', useValue: 42 }` and then `constructor(@Inject('MY_TOKEN') private value: number)`

Comment: @yurzui Strings as tokens do seem to work. Any idea why that is and if there's a way to use proper tokens?

Comment: @yurzui For now we can do `export MY_TOKEN: InjectionToken<…> = "MY_TOKEN" as any;` which hides the hack from the usage side, but it would be nice to figure this out properly.

Comment: It doesn't work for propert tokens because you're tokens are from different physical places and Angular uses `instanceof` to check token

Comment: That makes sense (and is unfortunate). Do you think the workaround approach I described above is a good strategy to approach this long-term then?

Comment: Also, I assume using interfaces for injection will have the same issue and we're basically forced to always use such fake-string tokens, right?

Comment: You can use tokens that are shared between modules

Comment: Ah, good point. I will have to try that out. We're actually facing the issue that the externals in the plugin bundles don't seem to actually be removed, but that's still on the todo list for another day for now.

Comment: @yurzui Simply adding our library (containing the tokens) as an external solved the issue. Thank you! :-) If you would like to drop it as a quick answer I can also mark it accepted and the bounty can go to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main caveat when using tokens for providers in Angular is that **a token, which we  declare in providers and inject in classes, must be imported from the same physical place**. One exception is a string token.

This means that if you have `const MY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken('MY TOKEN');` in one js file and have the same definition in another file then you might face this issue if provide and inject different tokens.

So your solution is **use either strings as a token or use tokens which are shared between bundles**.